# curl_exec() outputting destination contents to page?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init('www.google.com');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is not the first time I've used cURL, and unless I'm mistaken the above code should retrieve the contents of google.com and store it in $output. Correct?

So, why then, does the above code output the contents (in this example the Google homepage) to the page? I'm not echo'ing anything out, but for some reason the `curl_exec()` function is outputting what it returns to the page.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

That will tell curl_exec not to output the results

so change it all to

```
$ch = curl_init('www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```